# How do you extract epi Week from date using python?

Tags: python, date

I am trying to extract the epiweek from a pandas dataframe with the library "epiweeks" but i have some problems doing it.

mi code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from epiweeks import Week, Year

 a= [('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-11 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00'),
 ('2021-06-18 00:00:00')]
b = [25,58,65,45,47,85,96,36,25,14,25,78,75]

fecha = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)))

fecha[0] = pd.to_datetime(fecha[0])

Week.fromdate(fecha[0])
```

with this code I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

can you help me to find my wrong

Do you know another way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!

The only thing that you're doing wrong is you pass the whole `Series` to `fromdate`:

```py
Week.fromdate(fecha[0])
```

That won't work, because `Week.fromdate` expects a `datetime` or a `pandas.Timestamp`. But you can call `fecha[0].apply` on the series, which takes a function, and calls that function for each item in the series, and adds the value that the function returns to a new series, and then returns that series. You can then add that series to the dataframe like so:

```py
fecha['week'] = fecha[0].apply(Week.fromdate)
```

Or, if you want to pass some custom parameters to `Week.fromdate`:

```py
fecha['week'] = fecha[0].apply(lambda x: Week.fromdate(x, ...))
```

Try it:

```py
>>> fecha
            0   1    week
0  2021-06-11  25  202123
1  2021-06-11  58  202123
2  2021-06-11  65  202123
3  2021-06-11  45  202123
4  2021-06-11  47  202123
5  2021-06-11  85  202123
6  2021-06-18  96  202124
7  2021-06-18  36  202124
8  2021-06-18  25  202124
9  2021-06-18  14  202124
10 2021-06-18  25  202124
11 2021-06-18  78  202124
12 2021-06-18  75  202124

>>> fecha['week'][0]
Week(2021, 23, CDC)

>>> fecha['week'][12]
Week(2021, 24, CDC)
```

Comment: Great! it was easy. Thak you so much for help me.